# How can I implement an inset box-shadow in IE 8+?

Tags: html, css

What is the IE 8+ compatible CSS code for the following `box-shadow` code:

```
.border {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="border" style="background: url(http://c.saavncdn.com/UNI-04945-150x150.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: Try [PIE](http://css3pie.com/), it should help.

Comment: Note that `box-shadow` works fine in IE 9.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 supports this property except the value **inset**.